# SQL Server - Conflicts column type during UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

Need some help. I am creating SQL server unit testings that checks email server configurations and I'm having a weird behavior when using UNPIVOT. The following code will throw error when it runs on the vendor database but it works fine in default databases (master, model, msdb, tempdb). Any thought?

> Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
> The type of column "port" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

```
        SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT 
                CAST(p.name AS VARCHAR(256)) name, 
                CAST(a.email_address AS VARCHAR(256)) email_address, 
                CAST(a.display_name AS VARCHAR(256)) display_name, 
                CAST(a.replyto_address AS VARCHAR(256)) replyto_address,
                CAST(s.servertype AS VARCHAR(256)) servertype,  
                CAST(s.servername AS VARCHAR(256)) servername,
                CAST(s.port AS VARCHAR(256)) port
                FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile p 
                JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount pa ON p.profile_id = pa.profile_id 
                JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_account a ON pa.account_id = a.account_id 
                JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_server s ON a.account_id = s.account_id
            ) AS dummyName1
            UNPIVOT(
                configValue for configKey IN (name, email_address, display_name, replyto_address, servertype, servername, port)
            )   as dummyName2
```

Comment: If you use a `VALUES` table construct to unpivot the table instead, so you suffer the same problem?

Comment: It's possible the vendor database has a different collation set than the msdb database. The other columns are varchar so the cast carries over the existing collation, but port is not so it takes the default collation from the command context. You could check by adding "COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT" after each column to force them all to the same collation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that it works from some databases and not from others, the likeliest culprit is collation.

When you cast a varchar/nvarchar column to varchar/nvarchar, it will maintain its existing collation. When you cast another type like int (like the port column), it takes the default collation of the database from which you're executing the query. If the vendor database has a different collation than msdb, then the unpivot will give the error you're seeing.

A couple possible fixes:

1. Add this before your query to force it to execute from msdb:

   ```
   USE msdb;
   ```
2. Manually force your port column to use the same collation as msdb:

   ```
   --Check the collation for msdb
   SELECT name,collation_name FROM master.sys.databases
   --Use that collation (ex: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) in your query
   CAST(s.port AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS port
   ```
3. Force the other columns to use the same default collation that port is getting:

   ```
   CAST(p.name AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT name, 
   CAST(a.email_address AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT email_address,
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried Larnu solution yet but what bt224 mentioned about the collate solved the problem. The default database uses SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS while the vendor database uses Latin1_General_CI_AS.
Here is the updated code and it works! Thanks bt224!

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT 
                CAST(p.name AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT name, 
                CAST(a.email_address AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT email_address, 
                CAST(a.display_name AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT display_name, 
                CAST(a.replyto_address AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT replyto_address,
                CAST(s.servertype AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT servertype,  
                CAST(s.servername AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT servername,
                CAST(s.port AS VARCHAR(256)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT port
                FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile p 
                JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount pa ON p.profile_id = pa.profile_id 
                JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_account a ON pa.account_id = a.account_id 
                JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_server s ON a.account_id = s.account_id
            ) AS dummyName1
            UNPIVOT(
                configValue for configKey IN (name, email_address, display_name, replyto_address, servertype, servername, port)
            )   as dummyName2
```